# What abilities are available to a Leader from the Leader mod?

Tags: mods, xcom-2

Xcom 2 released with 3 mods available from the guys that made The Long War mod for Xcom at launch. (Before launch, even, for those with preview copies) One of these mods introduced a new skill tree for high ranking soldiers that provide leadership themed bonuses. What skills can be learned, and what do they do?

Comment: I'm kind of torn on how to ask/tag this question since the mod is semi-official. It's technically not part of the base game, but it's endorsed by the people that made the base game. Are there any relevant discussions on meta? Should there be a new one?

Comment: Mods are okay as long as it's not a troubleshooting "help xcom crashes after installing x mod"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Fireteam leader**

- Collector - Killing any non-human enemy has a 50% chance to grant 1 intel point as long as the leader is healthy.
- Get Some - Once per mission, spend an action to grant all allies within Command Range a +20 bonus to Critical Hit chances for the remainder of the turn.

**Squad Leader**

- Defilade - Soldiers within Command Range of the leader receive +5 bonus to defense value provided by cover.
- Focus Fire - Spend an action to pinpoint a target and grant your squad cumulative Aim bonuses and 1 Armor Piercing on attacks against that target for the rest of the turn.

**Section Leader**

- Fall Back! - Spend an action to grant a free but uncontrolled defensive action to any visible ally.
- Scavenger - Mission rewards of supplies, Alien Alloys and Elerium increased by 30% after successful missions. Chance of collecting extra Alien Alloys and Elerium from aliens.

**Troop Leader**

- Fire Discipline - All allies within Command Range of the leader gain +10% to hit on reaction fire.
- Oscar Mike - Spend an action to give all allies within Command Range +3 Mobility for the remainder of the turn. Usable once per mission.

**Field Commander**

- Lead by Example - The leader improves the Aim, Will and Hack of soldiers within Command Range by half the difference between soldier and leader.
- Combined Arms - All allies within Command Range of the leader do +1 damage with all successful attacks.

Source: Inside the mod `LW_OfficerPack/Localization/XComGame.int`

Comment: Holy crap those are good bonuses. Would any of those stack with a second leader?

Comment: You can't take two leaders on a mission at all. Be very careful with making multiple leaders.

Comment: @user2357112 "Except in dire situations" states the game. I presume that is when the ufo is grounded and you have to defend with up to 10? people.